# appending data from dictionaries to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I'm attempting to create a dataframe from dictionaries. The dictionaries can have many key, value pairs. The number of key, value pairs depends on the list of names.

Let's say I have a list of the following names:

```
names = [["name_0", "name_1"], ["name_2", "name_3"], ["name_2", "name_3", "name_4"]]
```

Since I have 3 lists of names, I'm going to create 3 dictionaries and pass some values. The keys in those dictionaries match the names from the list above. For this example I'm only passing 2 values but the lists can be longer than that.

```
dict_1 = {"name_0" : [1,2], "name_1" : [1,2]}
dict_2 = {"name_2" : [2,3], "name_3" : [1,3]}
dict_3 = {"name_2" : [2,3], "name_3" : [1,3], "name_4" : [2,3]}
#adding all dictionaries to a list
data_3 = [dict_1, dict_2, dict_3]
```

desired output:

```
                        names  values   multi
0           [name_0, name_1]   [1, 1]      1
1           [name_0, name_1]   [2, 2]      4
2           [name_2, name_3]   [2, 1]      2
3           [name_2, name_3]   [3, 3]      9
4  [name_2, name_3, name_4]   [2, 1, 2]    4
5  [name_2, name_3, name_4]   [3, 3, 3]    27
```

The values column is the combinations of all possible values from the dictionary values. Multi column is a multiplication of those values.

What I already tried:

```
names = [["name_0", "name_1"], ["name_2", "name_3"], ["name_2", "name_3", "name_4"]]
dict_1 = {"name_0" : [1,2], "name_1" : [1,2]}
dict_2 = {"name_2" : [2,3], "name_3" : [1,3]}
dict_3 = {"name_2" : [2,3], "name_3" : [1,3], "name_4" : [2,3]}
#adding all dictionaries to a list
data_3 = [dict_1, dict_2, dict_3]


def dict_operation(dictionary, names):
    df_data = []
    for i in names:
        for d in dictionary:
            for v in d.values():
                if len(i) > 2:
                    x = 0  # not sure how to do this part
                    df_data.append({"names": i, "values": v, "multi": x})
                else:
                    x = 0 # not sure how to do this part
                    df_data.append({"names" : i, "values": v, "multi" : x})
    #         if len(i) > 1:
    #             df_data.append({"names": i, "values" : v, "multi" : [2]})
    #         else:
    #             df_data.append({"names": i, "values": v, "multi": [2]})
    df=pd.DataFrame(df_data)
    print(df)
    return df

dict_operation(data_3, names)
```

I can't think of better way than those nested for loops. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some updates to simplify the code and made comments in the code to explain the changes. Hopefully this will help

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict_1 = {"name_0" : [1,2], "name_1" : [1,2]}
dict_2 = {"name_2" : [2,3], "name_3" : [1,3]}
dict_3 = {"name_2" : [2,3], "name_3" : [1,3], "name_4" : [2,3]}
#adding all dictionaries to a list
data_3 = [dict_1, dict_2, dict_3]


def dict_operation(dictionaries):
    df_data = []
    for d in dictionaries:
        # Names are already in the keys of each dict, so don't need to pass a list of names
        names = list(d.keys())
        # Zip the values (lists) within a dict to get combinations of elements by position
        for vals in zip(*d.values()):
            
            df_data.append({
                "names": names,
                "values": list(vals),  # zip will output a tuple, so convert to list
                "multi": np.prod(vals)  # numpy prod will take the product of all elements
            })
    df=pd.DataFrame(df_data)
    print(df)
    return df

dict_operation(data_3)
```

Thanks for putting the desired output - that was very helpful.

Comment: that looks great! I just thought about one scenario when: dict_1 = {"name_0" : 2, "name_1" : 1]} -> just noticed that np.prod doesn't like when there is only one value

Comment: The way the function is written, it expects a dictionary's values to be lists. If you want to have only one value for a given name, you'll need a list of length one - for example:
`dict_1 = {"name_0" : [2], "name_1" : [1]]}`. 
The function `np.prod` takes an array. If the array is length of one, it just returns the single input value. If the array is empty, it just returns `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand how `names` relates to `dict_1, dict_2, dict_3`, but this is what I got:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

names = [["name_0", "name_1"], ["name_2", "name_3"], ["name_2", "name_3", "name_4"]]

dict_1 = {"name_0" : [1,2], "name_1" : [1,2]}
dict_2 = {"name_2" : [2,3], "name_3" : [1,3]}
dict_3 = {"name_2" : [2,3], "name_3" : [1,3], "name_4" : [2,3]}
data_3 = [dict_1, dict_2, dict_3]

data_dict = {
    'names': [],
    'values': [],
    'multi': []
}
for dict_ in data_3:
    for i in range(2):
        data_dict['names'].append(str(list(dict_.keys())))
        values_list = [value[i] for value in dict_.values()]
        data_dict['values'].append(values_list)
        data_dict['multi'].append(np.prod(values_list))
    
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
print(data_df)
```